# Neural Network Accuracy Plateauing

Tags: c++, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I am making a neural network for the purpose of identifying letters. Currently, during training, the network seems to plateau at around 12% accuracy. As input, the network takes a 10x10 image (formatted as a 100x1 column vector) and outputs a 26x1 column vector where each element corresponds to a different letter. Right now I don't have a great data set (only 50 samples) but I iterate over it a few hundred times, and each iteration the accuracy doesn't really get any better than 6 / 50 correct. What I consider a correct identification is the element that corresponds to the correct letter being the greatest number in the vector. I was hoping to get a decently good accuracy before moving on and expanding the data set.

```
ML::Matrix ML::NeuralNetwork::calculate(const Matrix & input)
{
    //all inputs and layers are column vectors
    //weights and biases are std::vector of ML::Matrix
    Matrix resultant = input;
    results.add(resultant); //circular linked list to store the intermediate results
    for (int i = 0; i < weights.size(); ++i) {
        resultant = (weights[i] * resultant) + biases[i];
        resultant.function(sigmoid); //apply sigmoid to every element in the matrix
        results.add(resultant);
    }
    return resultant;
}

void ML::NeuralNetwork::learn(const Matrix & calc, const Matrix & real)
{
    //backpropagation
    ML::Matrix cost = 2 * (calc - real); //derivative of cost function: (calc - real)^2
    for (int i = weights.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        ML::Matrix dCdB = cost.hadamardProduct(ML::sigDerivative(weights[i] * results[i] + biases[i]));
        ML::Matrix dCdW = dCdB * results[i].transpose();
        cost = weights[i].transpose() * dCdB;
        weights[i] -= learningRate * dCdW;
        biases[i] -= learningRate * dCdB;
    }

}
ML::Matrix ML::Matrix::operator*(const Matrix & other) const throw(ML::MathUndefinedException)
{
    //naive matrix-multiplication and matrix-vector product
    if (columns != other.rows) throw MathUndefinedException();
    Matrix output(rows, other.columns);
    if (other.columns == 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
                output.set(i, output.get(i) + get(i, j) * other.get(j));
        }
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j) {
                for (int k = 0; k < other.rows; ++k) {
                    output.set(i, j, output.get(i, j) + get(i, k) * other.get(k, j));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

My network does work better with simpler examples. In a test with 3 inputs and 1 output it plateaus at about 70% and in another test with only 1 input and 1 output it would get around 99% accuracy so I am not certain if there is a problem with the code. While the code is abstracted for n layers of any size, I have been testing with around 1 - 2 hidden layers (total of 3 - 4 layers). I have tested various training rates, even non constant and differential training rates. I have tested each individual matrix manipulation function on its own (hadamardProduct, transposing, matrix addition etc.) so I am almost certain the problem isn't in one of those functions (thus, I didn't show their code with the exception of matrix multiplication)

All help will be appreciated

Comment: How many classes do you have? Mind that ANN are typically used with very large data sets, as the system needs to learn features from scratch. With very small number of samples you should rather do some clever feature engineering yourself.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski I only have two, the Neural Network class and the Matrix class. This may sound dumb, but I was kind of expecting that the only problem with the small data set is that the model would be heavily overfitted, especially after making thousands of iterations over the data.